# delete string with certain values from list in python

Tags: python

i have list

```
my_list = ['Cat Dog Tiger Lion', 'Elephant Crocodile Monkey', 'Pantera Cat Eagle Hamster']
```

i need to delete all of elements which containing `sub = 'Cat'`

so i need to have output

```
['Elephant Crocodile Monkey']
```

i think i need to do something with regex, maybe `re.compile` to find this values and then drop them from `my_list`?

i have been tryed:

```
for string in my_list:
    if string.find(sub) is not -1:
        print("this string have our sub")
    else:
        print("sthis string doesnt have our sub")
```

but i dont know how to combine it with delete this rows from `my_list`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter lists, a simple approach is to use a list comprehension:

```
[i for i in my_list if 'Cat' not in i]
# ['Elephant Crocodile Monkey']
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
out = []
for i in my_list:
    if 'Cat' not in i:
        out.append(i)
```

Comment: Nice @yatu. Would this als cater for `Cat` being a substring though? I am keen to learn on how you would adapt your answer to make it work when `Cat` would be a substring of `Caterpillar`. I've added an answer myself but I feel that it can be done much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your list:

```
my_list = ['Cat Dog Tiger Lion', 'Elephant Crocodile Monkey', 'Pantera Cat Eagle Hamster']
```

You can use list comprehension for filtering the list:

```
new_list = [x for x in my_list if(not x.__contains__('Cat'))]
```

Comment: For learning purposes. Could you explain the main differences between `not in` as per @yatu his answer and your `not contains` method?

Comment: The `in` keyword calls the `__contains__ `method of the object. I realize that `in` is more preferable as it is easier than method-call syntax. However, both of them give the same result.